# Implement code which launch measure periodically

Tags: android, time

I'm trying to develop a field teest application (android). So I'm want to give user choice to launch measure periodically (). My question is how can I implements it!

Zim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Thread(){
@Override
public void run(){
   autoUpdate = new Timer();
   autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              // TODO
          }
       });
      }
    },0,10000);//updates each 10 sec.
 }
 }.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use alarmmanager to trigger your app periodically

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
alarmManager.setRepeating(int type, long first_time,long interval, PendingIntent intent_to_your_app);
```

ref : [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: Make sure you do *not* use a service, this is sound advice from @ethan_liou